# Почему не выводится CSS?

Tags: html, css

На моей странице не отображается `background` и при этом к последнему блоку не применяются правила   CSS. Делаю все по этому видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSkqo8hEATw&t=97s
но все равно ошибки. Вот код HTML:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i');

/* Шрифт из гугл + добавление font-family, sans-serif шрифт по умолчанию, если шрифт гугл не прогрузился */

body {
  background: url(images/18.jpg);
  можно записать все в одну строку */
}
#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.strong-red {
  margin-top: 400px;
  color: #30a7ff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.light-blue {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.light-blue {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: blackl;
}
#style li {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  list-style-type: ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Название страницы</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <p class="strong-red">Я работаю веб-дизайнером. Какое-то время назад я подрабатывала фрилансером, сейчас работаю в небольшой студии. У нас нет менеджера проектов, поэтому, зачастую, я сама выступаю этим самым менеджером, по совместительству.
      <br>Опыт общения с самыми разными заказчиками у меня достаточно большой. Статья «Краткая инструкция по работе с web-дизайнером (для менеджера проекта)» вызвала у меня шквал эмоций и бурю негодования, потому что именно таких заказчиков я всегда старалась
      избегать. В этой статье я попробую описать, как в идеале должна проходить работа заказчика и дизайнера.
    </p>
    <p>
      <ul id="styles">
        <li>Пункт 1</li>
        <li>Пункт 2</li>
        <li>Пункт 3</li>
        <li>Пункт 4</li>
        <li>Пункт 5</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на SO. Я переформатировал код в вашем вопросе, добавив его в сниппет — теперь есть возможность выполнить его прямо в браузере. Ещё у вас не было возможности редактировать вопрос (вероятно из-за того, что не зарегистрировали учётку сразу), теперь есть — используйте кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 2):

В таблице стилей и в html должен быть соответственно одинаковый идентификатор:
 `#styles li` и   `<ul id="styles">`

Проверьте путь до файла, который используется в качестве background

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i');


body {
 background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ljug3pp.jpg);
background-size: cover;
}
#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.strong-red {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: brown;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.light-blue {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}
.light-blue {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
}
#styles li {
  color: brown;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  list-style-type: ;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Название страницы</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <p class="strong-red">Я работаю веб-дизайнером. Какое-то время назад я подрабатывала фрилансером, сейчас работаю в небольшой студии. У нас нет менеджера проектов, поэтому, зачастую, я сама выступаю этим самым менеджером, по совместительству.
      <br>Опыт общения с самыми разными заказчиками у меня достаточно большой. Статья «Краткая инструкция по работе с web-дизайнером (для менеджера проекта)» вызвала у меня шквал эмоций и бурю негодования, потому что именно таких заказчиков я всегда старалась
      избегать. В этой статье я попробую описать, как в идеале должна проходить работа заказчика и дизайнера.
    </p>
    <p>
      <ul id="styles">
        <li>Пункт 1</li>
        <li>Пункт 2</li>
        <li>Пункт 3</li>
        <li>Пункт 4</li>
        <li>Пункт 5</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Коментарий уже закрыли)))
Зачем опять-то закрывать.

```css
body {
  background: url(images/18.jpg);
}
#style li {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  list-style-type: ;
}
```

И еще забыли написать `list-style-type: ;`.

Comment: Вот попробовал как вы написали. Все равно не работает- не пойму, хоть убейте( https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2njx.png
И еще не понимаю почему списка тэги стали красными(

Comment: и вот что выдает браузер. даже намека нет на то что мне надо https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8mlM.png

Comment: У вас в сниппете код css находился в блоке html – точно ничего не перепутали? )

Comment: Уберите абзац которым вы обертываете елементы списка(17 строка)

Comment: И еще. Если вы хотите чтобы блок текста отображался вверху страницы(не посредине, как у вас) то сделайте .strong-red {
  margin-top: 400px;

Comment: @ThusMad а можно узнать как связана 17 строка и style? все равно бэкграунд не появляется и к тексту не применяется. После удаления 17 строки style стал синим в brackets, но увы особых изменений я не нашел) Буду рад вашему ответу, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: 17 строка в Html разметке. Желательно  записать как-то так:                                           background-image: url(../images/18.jpg) no-repeat(если не нужно повторение изображения).

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставьте одинарные или двойные скобки

   `background-image: url('images/18.jpg');`
2. `id="styles"` , В css `style li {...}`

Измените `id` или в `html`  или  в `css` ...

Comment: [Поправте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/767484/edit) ответ. Там вверху есть справка.

Answer (score 0):

Комментарии в коде, так понятней...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300i');

/* Шрифт из гугл + добавление font-family, sans-serif шрифт по умолчанию, если шрифт гугл не прогрузился */

body {
  /*ни каких ковычек не надо, просто проверь путь в файлу, видать путь не правильный*/
  background: url(http://www.hqwallpapers.ru/wallpapers/nature/magicheskie-gory.jpg);
  /*можно записать все в одну строку */
}

#page {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.strong-red {
  margin-top: 400px;
  color: #30a7ff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  background: #55555599;
}

.light-blue {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
}

.light-blue {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: blackl;
}


/* тут в селекторе пропущена буква было
style а надо styles
по этому и не применялись стили
*/

#styles li {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Cuprum", sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Название страницы</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <p class="strong-red">Я работаю веб-дизайнером. Какое-то время назад я подрабатывала фрилансером, сейчас работаю в небольшой студии. У нас нет менеджера проектов, поэтому, зачастую, я сама выступаю этим самым менеджером, по совместительству.
      <br>Опыт общения с самыми разными заказчиками у меня достаточно большой. Статья «Краткая инструкция по работе с web-дизайнером (для менеджера проекта)» вызвала у меня шквал эмоций и бурю негодования, потому что именно таких заказчиков я всегда старалась
      избегать. В этой статье я попробую описать, как в идеале должна проходить работа заказчика и дизайнера.
    </p>
    <p>
      <ul id="styles">
        <li>Пункт 1</li>
        <li>Пункт 2</li>
        <li>Пункт 3</li>
        <li>Пункт 4</li>
        <li>Пункт 5</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```